# Hibernate: Restart instead of Shutting Down

Tags: windows, linux, ubuntu, hibernate, reboot

### The Situation

I have sort of an odd request. I dual boot Ubuntu and Windows and sometimes I just want to switch between the partitions without loosing the state of the OS I was currently working with. Currently to do that I just hibernate that OS and, when the computer turns off, I restart it and select the correct partition.

### The Issue

I do not really want to have to press the on button again every time I want to switch between partitions. I figure that there must be a way to make the hibernate action restart instead of shutting down.

### The Question

How do I make the hibernate action restart instead of shutting down on:

- Windows, or
- Ubuntu

Thank you for any help here. I am hoping that there is a way to do that on both operating systems but if you can atleast tell me one then that would be much appreciated.

P.S. It is more important to me that I can do this in Ubuntu than Windows (because of the way I use the partitions) therefore if one answer says the Ubuntu way and the other says the Windows way then I will mark the Ubuntu one as the answer and give the Windows one an upvote and a big thankyou.

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that if you want to use the same disk partitions in both OSes a full shutdown would be safer. http://superuser.com/q/211079/31641.

Answer (score 3):

On Ubuntu I found out that pm-hibernate from pmutils nearly has this functionality. If you put this in the config file then it will always restart:

```
HIBERNATE_MODE=reboot
```

That is okay but I do not want hibernate to always reboot. Sometimes I want a reboot and sometimes I want a shutdown. However, what this does mean is that I should be able to do a little bit of coding and get pm-hibernate to run like this:

```
pm-hibernate --hibernate-mode=reboot
```

And that will be Ubuntu done. I am still looking for better answers though that do not require me to do any work if possible. (And I still do not know how to do this for Windows)