# Unable to access folders made by Ubuntu under Windows 7 (dual boot)

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, multi-boot

I have installed Ubuntu 10.04 (now 10.10) in a partition, with windows 7 already installed.

From Ubuntu I can access 2 hard disks of Windows 7 ie. C: and E:
I can easily access content from Ubuntu, and also paste files inside C: or E:

The trouble comes when I create directory inside C: or E: from Ubuntu and then try to access it from Windows 7.

First Windows opens up "the folder" but shows nothing inside it, and gives a error (that it cannot open the folder).

Second trouble: I saved some videos from Ubuntu, inside a folder created by Ubuntu in C:.
Again Windows 7 did not show contents of this folder. And when I accessed this folder from Ubuntu, "the folder" vanished, and of course the contents vanished.

Please tell me why this is happening? And if and how I can recover that data?

**EDIT:** As suggested, I made a *test* folder in C: from Ubuntu, and changed its permissions. Though the permissions didn't seem to change (i.e doing `ls -l` showed same permissions as before) I properly shut down while switching from one to another this time, but some times I "resume windows from hibernation". The *test* folder was accessible, with a image inside also accessible, with no problem.

I am not sure what did the trick. But my updated question is **how I can recover that data?**.

Comment: Put in your question the means by which you are switching operating systems: proper shutdown or hibernation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### When Microsoft said "[Do not make major changes to the computer's state after you put the computer in hibernation or on standby.](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/907477)", it meant it.

> some times I "resume windows from hibernation"

That's your problem, the reason that your test worked when you didn't do it, and the reason that I commented.  **Don't do that.**  Like the other SuperUser contributors in that mountain of tales of woe, listed in further reading, you have managed to severely corrupt your disc volume.  The very first thing that you need to do is force a run of `chkdsk` against the volume, because it has become corrupt in a way that doesn't tell Windows that it might need to scan it for problems.  Your data *may not be* recoverable at this point, depending from what each operating system thought was free space on the volume.

**If you want to bootstrap another operating system, *shut down*.**

#### Further reading

- [Does Windows 7 deleted files generated during hibernation?](https://superuser.com/q/384381/38062)

Comment: Thanks, the data was fortunately not important, but please tell me if the corrupted data would be taking(wasting) up space on disk.

Answer (score 1):

The first trouble can be because of permission issues. Check the permissions of the folder you create.

Comment: `ls test/ -l` returns `-rw-------`. I created the folder test using right click menu inside C:

Comment: That means only owner of the directory can read and write on the folder. No one else. If you want it to be accessible from any other user account or windows, run `chmod 755 test/` on the folder. Or you can also change the permissions from right clicking on the folder, go to permissions and change the permissions there. http://i.imgur.com/p4iDa.png