# Cant see files(created by windows) on NTFS Partition

Tags: windows, ubuntu, ntfs

I have a NTFS Disk that is use to share all my media files betweeon Windows 7 and Ubuntu. Unforntunately after i saved some new movies there using windows i cant not see them in Ubuntu. I just wont "refresh" and show the new .avi files. They work pretty well in windows.

Why?

//EDIT:
output of ls -la. It is missing the whole Stargate season 5 as avi files, that I added in Windows. In Windows i can open those files and view them without any problem. 
Linux was in hibernate while adding them in Windows.

> total 25945372
>   drwxrwxrwx 1 root root      61440 Dez 14 22:01 .
>   drwxr-xr-x 8 root root       4096 Nov 24 21:55 ..
>   drwxrwxrwx 1 root root          0 Dez 10 22:05 AC4_D.D.E_v1.01.HF.2_UPD_V10C
>   drwxrwxrwx 1 root root          0 Dez 10 22:26 AC4_D.D.E_V9M
>   drwxrwxrwx 1 root root          0 Okt 21 23:26 ADOBE_ACROBAT_XI_PRO.V11.0_MULTI-XFORCE
>   -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 1071148151 Mai 31  2013 Anger.Management.S02E20.PROPER.720p.HDTV.x264-EVOLVE.mkv
>   -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 1195218670 Okt 10 09:44 Arrow.S02E01.720p.HDTV.X264-DIMENSION.mkv
>   drwxrwxrwx 1 root root          0 Okt 21 23:26 BBTHD.702
>   -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 1458256182 Jun  8  2013 Da.Vincis.Demons.S01E08.720p.HDTV.x264-EVOLVE.mkv
>   drwxrwxrwx 1 root root          0 Dez  8 15:26 Die.Tribute.von.Panem.Catching.Fire.2013.German.NEW.R6.LD.XviD-TOD
>   drwxrwxrwx 1 root root          0 Dez  8 15:25 Die.Tribute.von.Panem.Catching.Fire.NEW.SOURCE.TS.LD.German.XViD-4TH
>   drwxrwxrwx 1 root root          0 Dez  7 16:36 Die.Tribute.Von.Panem.German.DL.720p.BluRay.x264-SONS
>   -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 2422951679 Nov 24 16:10 Doctor.Who.S07S03.50th.Anniversary.Special.Der.Tag.des.Doktors.German.DL.DD51.Dubbed.720p.HDTV.x264-GDR.mkv
>   drwxrwxrwx 1 root root          0 Okt 21 23:26 DxtHD.805
>   drwxrwxrwx 1 root root          0 Dez  7 16:51 Elysium.German.720p.BluRay.x264-EXQUiSiTE
>   -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4012686983 Jul 10 12:21 empire-40-720p.mkv
>   -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root       8258 Jul 10 14:01 empire-40-720p.nfo
>   -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root    2199552 Apr 11  2012 encounters-letmein_720p_ger.sub
>   drwxrwxrwx 1 root root          0 Okt 21 23:29 Europa.Report.2013.German.DTS.DL.1080p.BluRay.x264-HP
>   drwxrwxrwx 1 root root          0 Okt 21 23:29 fdx3k.Security.Task.Manager.1.8d.cracked-SND
>   drwxrwxrwx 1 root root          0 Okt 21 23:32 fifa 14
>   drwxrwxrwx 1 root root          0 Okt 21 23:32 HMM7p.905
>   drwxrwxrwx 1 root root          0 Okt 24 00:01 HMMHD.906rp
>   drwxrwxrwx 1 root root      24576 Dez  1 23:26 House.at.the.End.of.the.Street.Extended.German.DL.1080p.BluRay.x264-ETM
>   drwxrwxrwx 1 root root       4096 Okt 25 03:43 Ich.Einfach.unverbesserlich.2.German.DTS.720p.BluRay.x264-HP
>   -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 2379292775 Jul 25 04:47 Ich.Einfach.unverbesserlich.German.2010.AAC.720p.BluRay.H264-iND.m4v
>   drwxrwxrwx 1 root root       4096 Okt 25 02:31 Inside.Was.Sie.Will.Ist.In.Dir.UNCUT.GERMAN.2007.720p.BluRay.x264-GOREHOUNDS
>   -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 1849327616 Feb 19  2013 i-ttacs6daww.iso
>   drwxrwxrwx 1 root root       4096 Nov 11 21:39 Jackass.Bad.Grandpa.TS.LD.German.XviD-PL
>   drwxrwxrwx 1 root root      20480 Okt 24 14:37 Kindskoepfe.2.GERMAN.DL.AC3.Dubbed.720p.BluRay.x264.iNTERNAL-SOV
>   -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  107999608 Jul 19  2012 lucid.mp3
>   -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  960634279 Okt  2 10:19 Marvels.Agents.of.S.H.I.E.L.D.S01E02.720p.HDTV.X264-DIMENSION.mkv
>   -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  956390632 Okt  9 08:21 Marvels.Agents.of.S.H.I.E.L.D.S01E03.720p.HDTV.X264-DIMENSION.mkv
>   -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  267628569 Okt 17 14:31 mieten, kaufen, wohnen__Keine Provision, doppelte Arbeit.flv
>   drwxrwxrwx 1 root root       4096 Okt 28 11:52 MOHA USB
>   drwxrwxrwx 1 root root          0 Nov  7 15:00 Olympus.Has.Fallen.Die.Welt.in.Gefahr.2013.German.DTS.DL.1080p.BluRay.x264-RHD
>   drwxrwxrwx 1 root root          0 Nov 30 03:58 Pacific.Rim.2013.3D.H-SBS.German.DL.720p.BluRay.x264-LeetHD
>   -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 1461367611 Okt 17 21:04 Person.of.Interest.S03E04.720p.WEB-DL.DD5.1.H.264-KiNGS.mkv
>   -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 1009645947 Nov 19 00:40 Person.of.Interest.S03E06.720p.HDTV.X264-DIMENSION.mkv
>   -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  910423155 Nov 19 00:46 Person.of.Interest.S03E07.720p.HDTV.X264-DIMENSION.mkv
>   -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  930548344 Nov 19 00:43 Person.of.Interest.S03E08.720p.HDTV.X264-DIMENSION.mkv
>   drwxrwxrwx 1 root root       4096 Dez  1 21:47 Prakti.com.UNRATED.German.DL.1080p.BluRay.x264-EXQUiSiTE
>   -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 1168747621 Jul  8 08:32 Ray.Donovan.S01E02.REPACK.720p.HDTV.x264-IMMERSE.mkv
>   -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 1116539061 Jul 15 07:44 Ray.Donovan.S01E03.720p.HDTV.x264-IMMERSE.mkv
>   drwxrwxrwx 1 root root          0 Nov  1 00:09 $RECYCLE.BIN
>   drwxrwxrwx 1 root root       4096 Nov 30 03:34 Redemption.Stunde.der.Vergeltung.2013.German.DL.1080p.BluRay.x264-EXQUiSiTE
>   drwxrwxrwx 1 root root          0 Okt 21 23:33 Samy Molcho - Mit Körpersprache zum Erfolg
>   -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  681287680 Jun 26 22:47 soa-s01e01-dl-xvid.avi
>   drwxrwxrwx 1 root root          0 Nov 22 02:00 South-720-1705
>   drwxrwxrwx 1 root root          0 Nov 22 02:00 South-720-1706
>   drwxrwxrwx 1 root root          0 Nov 22 02:03 South-720-1707
>   drwxrwxrwx 1 root root          0 Nov 22 02:02 South-720-1708
>   -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  473135089 Aug 19 20:03 talking.bad.s01e02.720p.hdtv.x264-2hd.mkv
>   -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root          0 Dez 14 21:57 TESTEE
>   -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root          0 Dez 14 22:01 TESTEE2
>   -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  859840756 Okt 22 05:59 The.Blacklist.S01E05.720p.HDTV.X264-DIMENSION.mkv
>   drwxrwxrwx 1 root root       4096 Nov  7 14:51 The.Painter.Dein.Blut.ist.seine.Farbe.2012.German.DL.1080p.BluRay.x264-ENCOUNTERS
>   -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  201000429 Okt 26  2010 The Playbook.pdf
>   -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 1071596060 Jul 21 23:26 The.White.Queen.1×06.Love.And.Death.720p.HDTV.x264-FoV.mkv
>   drwxrwxrwx 1 root root          0 Okt 23 00:39 .Trash-1000

Comment: Besides `avi` can you see other files on the disk in Ubuntu?

Comment: Yes i can see many files.

Comment: OK. In Ubuntu could you go to this folder in terminal and type `ls -la`. It will list all files in this directory. Can you edit your post and add this data there so we can see it?

Answer (score 3):

### When Microsoft said "[Do not make major changes to the computer's state after you put the computer in hibernation or on standby.](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/907477)", it meant it.

> Linux was in hibernate while adding them in Windows.

Changes to the computer's state *include bootstrapping another operating system entirely and modifying what's on the hard disc*.  You've just witnessed what goes wrong when one does that: volumes become corrupt, files and directories (not at all) mysteriously look just like they did when the first operating system hibernated, strange errors occur.  [SuperUser has a whole mountain of tales of woe from people who tried this.](https://superuser.com/questions/39532/)

Hibernation is not shutdown.  The filesystem cache manager and all of the filesystem drivers retain their in-memory state across hibernation.  After all, that is the point.  This state includes open files, unwritten data and metadata in memory, and so forth.  During hibernation, the state of your volume(s) on disc isn't necessarily consistent, and isn't the state that it would be had the machine been actually shut down, with all of the files closed, transactions finished, and pending writes flushed.

During hibernation (of Windows, Linux, or indeed any other current operating system with this mechanism) …

- … **do not** mount any NTFS, FAT, or other types of disc volumes that were in use by the operating system that you hibernated, as anything other than *strictly read-only* from any operating system.
- … **do not** blithely and erroneously think that the only operations that could update the on-disc data structures for a volume are writing to files.

**If you want to bootstrap another operating system, *shut down*.**

#### Further reading

- Gilles (2010-11-15). [*"You need a reader-writer lock on each shared partition."*](https://superuser.com/a/211175/38062)  SuperUser.
- https://superuser.com/q/387607/387607