# Dual Boot Windows 10's in different partitions after hibernating?

Tags: boot, partitioning, hibernate

I have this question, that SEEMS to be answered but answers I  find in SU or other places in google, just talk about Dual Booting Windows-Linux or booting in the same partition.
Let me explain my case:

I have my SATA HDD partitioned. I have C:\ with 500 GB size and D:\ with 120 GB size.
In both partitions I have Windows 10 PRO, I can choose with which one to boot when I turn on my PC.

The problem is that 120 GB partition is the one I use for my work, and I have my work stuff, programs destined to work, etc.

The 500 GB partition is my home partition, I have a lot of games installed, movies, music, pictures, applications, etc.

I want to switch between OS without shuting down the one I use for work because I would have to re-open aaaaaaall my stuff of the works. I woul'd prefer to hibernate it, then switch to my 500GB partition with Windows 10, and when I need to work, shut it down and wake up the 120 GB partition from hibernating to continue my work as I left it.
I haven't tested it because I read that data may be corrupted or loss. So, it this safe and possible?

Comment: I don't think that is possible as I have tried it with Win7 and 10... But don't take my word for it.

Comment: @RACING121 :C jajajaja I will try it later jajaja

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can't I boot off another drive or change BIOS options after hibernating?](http://superuser.com/questions/526688/why-cant-i-boot-off-another-drive-or-change-bios-options-after-hibernating)