# Keeping Fast Startup for Windows 8 in a Win/Linux dual booting environment?

Tags: windows-8.1, multi-boot, linux-mint

I have some specific questions regarding Dual Booting Win8/Linux. It is recommended to disable Fast Startup for Windows 8 as it can cause **data loss**, but my boot times seems to go up a lot. If it is enabled, my Win8 boot time is 9 secs, and without it is around 35.

1. Can I keep Fast Startup activated if I don't plan to use the Windows partition from Linux at all? I've done some reading (like this [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/452071/why-disable-fast-boot-on-windows-8-when-having-dual-booting)) but haven't really answered my question.
2. I have a second NTFS partition for all my Files; is it possible to use a linux-based file system on this partition and keep all my Files in there, and be able to modify it from Linux, and also from Win8 (and keep Fast Startup enabled)?
3. Maybe this has been answered before... What about hibernation? It seems like you are able to hibernate both OS without issues ([link](https://superuser.com/questions/39532/hibernating-and-booting-into-another-os-will-my-filesystems-be-corrupted)).

Answer (score 3):

The articles in your question state that Ubuntu will refuse to mount NTFS partitions that it see's to be hibernated or with Fast Startup enabled.

They state that the danger only lies in trying to modify data partitions used by an OS with Fast Startup enabled, or is hibernated. This doesn't have the be a main operating system partition (such as `C:\`). Even secondary partitions used only for file storage are still at risk from data loss if they are mounted by that OS.

Since you stated in your question that you have a shared NTFS partition for all your files that you are accessing from Windows 8 *and* Linux, **DO NOT USE HIBERNATION OR FAST STARTUP**. You will risk data loss.

> [if you create a shared NTFS data partition the hibernation may maintain the file structure so if you try to save a file from Linux into the NTFS partition it will get lost on Windows reboot as it only remembers the old file structure.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/452071/why-disable-fast-boot-on-windows-8-when-having-dual-booting)

Even if you change the filesystem from NTFS to ext4 (the default filesystem used by Linux) to access it from both Linux and Windows (with fastboot enabled, or in hibernation), the danger is still the same.

*For more information on mountting `ext4` partitions in Windows 8 with software such as Ext2Fsd, see [this page](http://www.howtogeek.com/112888/3-ways-to-access-your-linux-partitions-from-windows/) for more information.*

Answer (score 0):

per question 1:
not without loosing boot time speed on windows

per question 2:
it would have to be fat16/32 or ntfs for BOTH OSes to see it and be able to modify it (not sure if fast boot would play a role but seems likely to some degree at least)

per question 3:

you can but as far as i know fastboot + hibernate is at best miserable and linux while capable depending on the distro of linux it gonna be hit and miss.

~sent from my linux box (fedora 22)