# Software to switch between OS

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, software-rec, multi-boot

My question might sound too weired and tricky, but is there any way (software/hardware) that I can use to switch between 2 OS without restarting my PC?

Actually I have Windows 7 and Ubuntu installed in my PC.

Comment: +1 Interesting question, and while I answered "no", it would be very cool if some great developer could create such a software.

Comment: well, if you ran everything over a hypervisor... maybe...

Comment: I'm pretty sure this question doesn't mean anything. What do you mean by 'without restarting my PC'?

Comment: The question seems pretty clear to me.

Comment: @KCotreau Then maybe you could take a second to explain it to us and answer @CarlF's question. This really isn't written clearly at all. Doesn't GRUB, which is installed with Ubuntu, do essentially this?

Comment: @Corey I would say that going into hibernation, when you come out, that counts as a restarting. I really think he means on the fly, but I though Carl's comment was just stupid..."doesn't mean anything"? He could say, could you clarify this point or that point, but his comment was glib at best.

Comment: I agree with all the many answers that say to use a VM of some sort ... but I can't be sure that's what @romilnagrani actually wanted.

Comment: @CarlF: He means on the fly.

Comment: @Kcontreau and others: the basic hypervisor technology is well known and is commercially available on Macs as [Parallels desktop](http://www.parallels.com/products/desktop/). I've watched people flip between instances of Mac Os and Windows running on the same hardware.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Well, i can think of two. One, run one of the OSes in a VM. The second is to get another system, and run the second OS on that. You can't switch between OSes without restarting.

If you wanted to save the state of the system, [you MIGHT be able to get away with hibernating windows, and starting linux as long as you do NOT write to the windows drive](https://superuser.com/questions/39532/hibernating-and-booting-into-another-os-will-my-filesystems-be-corrupted) - as you can tell from the answers, do this at your own risk. The other way seems to be safe, however.

If you wanted to build a system that would do this from scratch  you'd need a model similar to what the PS3 uses possibly on top of xen or another hypervisor
[image]

Comment: Yes, this is what I was thinking. GRUB handles a Windows hibernation and restores its state just fine.

Comment: it still involves restarting ;)

Comment: Ah yes, I had a false memory of my netbook going to GRUB upon restarting the OS (not the PC), but it looks like it restarts the PC and then launches GRUB. My bad, but I like your answer the best because it allows for the possibility that the question was asking that.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a virtual machine. One OS (e.g. Ubuntu) *hosts* another (e.g. Windows) as a *guest* in a virtual machine. An example is VirtualBox. Your guest OS will be just like another program inside your host OS.

Answer (score 2):

If you had two different OS running as virtual machines under a third operating system, you wouldn't strictly speaking have to restart the PC to switch between them.

Answer (score 2):

[kexec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kexec) allows you to boot a new linux kernel without rebooting your PC.
Currently, it only runs on linux (So it won't work on your particular setup, but would work to boot, for example, fedora from ubuntu).

[This proyect](https://www.jstump.com/projects/kexec/wiki) seems to be attempting to port kexec to windows, though I've failed to find how much progress they've made.  It should be an interesting starting point though.

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is no. The only thing close to that is virtualization. You could add a virtualization software to your Windows install (or vice versa), and then convert your current Linux install to a VM (there are tools to convert physical machines into VM's).

Comment: While I don't know if they are available on plain PC hardware, hypervisors allow one to run multi OS on the same hardware without software virtulization. The principle has been used in mainframes for a long time, and on has been available on Macs for quite a while (which implies that the CPU in a modern PC has the necessary hardware support).

Comment: @dmckee: "hypervisors allow one to run multi OS on the same hardware without software virtulization." - 
Not exactly. I mean, hypervisors *are* software; CPUs nowadays do support hardware virtualization, but you still need software to emulate I/O.

Answer (score 1):

You could run one of them as a VM in e.g. Virtualbox

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer:no. The OS needs to interact with the hardware, or at least it has to think it is. Without a hypervisor or virtualization system running underneath the OS, managing the hardware/OS interation and the switching, this is not possible with x86 architectures.

Answer (score 0):

Something like xen or kvm lets you switch between virtual machines very quickly and runs them with little overhead.

Comment: Is there a solution that supports Windows 7 (including Gaming) and Gentoo?

Comment: Both Xen and KVM support Windows 7 guests, according to their web sites. Gaming ... I haven't tried this (don't play games any more) so can't comment. Gentoo is fully supported by both, isn't it?

Comment: Went to check the FAQ, it says `The frequently asked question comes from people who want to use Windows in a HVM domain to play games or run high-end 3D graphics applications, and the answer here is "Not yet".`. :(

Comment: I had to look up "HVM" to interpret that ... but you're clearly right. Of course, it's my understanding that KVM and Xen were both created for server rather than workstation use, so not supporting 3D graphics is perhaps not surprising.  VirtualBox does support at least some 3D, but of course it's much slower.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure a program like Virtualbox or VMware to load your physical XP or Linux install (whichever isn't in use at that time) from within whichever OS you *are* using.

You can then boot into either OS normally on a reboot.

[Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=769883) has a guide on how to boot your physical XP install from within Ubuntu.

[VMware Communities](http://communities.vmware.com/thread/181914) has a guide for booting a physical Linux install from within Windows.

Note, you may need to install 2 copies of Grub for this to work.
Also, you will most certainly be required to have different hardware profiles for both operating systems and Windows will most likely have to be re-activated when you switch hardware profiles.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways you can run Windows and Linux distros on the same physical machine without rebooting the PC or notebook, use any of the VMs suggested, including Virtualbox which I am running on my MacbookPro and running both XP and other linux distros, CentOS, Fedora, Mint, Ubuntu, or use KVM or Xen. Check them out and configure your systems to install any one of these as the host and put the guest OS on it.