# Save Windows 7 session and start other OS

Tags: windows, ubuntu, hibernate, session

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Hibernating and booting into another OS: will my filesystems be corrupted?](https://superuser.com/questions/39532/hibernating-and-booting-into-another-os-will-my-filesystems-be-corrupted)

Frequently I use Windows' hibernation option. However, I miss one feature. I want to save my current session, which hibernation in fact does, and then reboot the machine to load my Ubuntu OS at startup.

Unfortunately I cannot figure out how this is going to work.

Comment: when you boot the machine after hibernating, don't you still get the opportunity to boot from an alternate partition?

Comment: Not automatically and not by pressing F8 or F12. Immediately Windows starts showing me the 'Resuming Windows' screen.

Is that different on your system?

Comment: @orschiro - This is how Windows designed the system.  They designed a feature to boot their own operating system after you hibernate only logical.

Comment: Thanks Ramhound. So there is no way to save a Window session and boot into another OS?

Comment: You may want to read [Hibernating and booting into another OS: will my filesystems be corrupted?](http://superuser.com/questions/39532/hibernating-and-booting-into-another-os-will-my-filesystems-be-corrupted) If you do this do not mount any of your NTFS volumes as writable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible, I do it on my laptop.  I dual-boot Windows 7 and Linux, and I can hibernate one and boot into the other, no problem.  The two systems shouldn't affect each other.  There's a few things that might be wrong:

Are you using hibernate to disk, or suspend (to ram)?  You need to use hibernate, or else you'll get the situation you describe.  In hibernate, all data is saved to disk and the computer uses no power - you can unplug it and pull the battery and still resume.  Suspend stops everything except the RAM, which still draws power.  If any lights remain on with the power cord unplugged, you're not in S4 hibernate - you need to enable it.

Hibernate needs to be supported in your BIOS, which it should be in any computer made in the last decade or so.  It also needs to be enabled in Windows.  Click the start orb and click the arrow next to the "shut down" button.  If something on that list says Hibernate, hibernate to disk is on in Windows and something else is the problem (check your BIOS).  If something there says Sleep, turn on hibernate to disk by doing the following: Go to Power Options in the Control Panel.  Click "change plan settings" next to your current power plan, expand "Sleep" and turn "Allow Hybrid Sleep" *off*.

If this doesn't work you might be loading the Windows bootloader before GRUB (the bootloader than Ubuntu installs), although this is unlikely because usually if that's the case you can't boot into Linux at all.  If my first suggestion doesn't work, I'll write something here about this.

Comment: How does one enable Hibernate in the BIOS? I'm curious.

Comment: Scratch that, I'm thinking of the difference between S1 and S3 sleep (you can generally set one or both on in the BIOS).  S4 sleep - hibernate - should either work or not work, I don't think there's normally a setting to turn it off.  If there is, the way to change the setting would vary depending on your BIOS.  I've edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks. I suspected you were talking about S3 sleep, but my experience around that is murky to say the least. I've never considered myself a hardware guy.

Comment: Hello ChimneyImp, Thanks for your extensive reply. Probably the bootloader is the exact problem. I installed Ubuntu with the help of Wubi. In this case the Windows bootloader is loaded and shows me Windows 7 and Ubuntu as choices. When selecting Ubuntu GRUB is started and shows me the different kernel versions to choose from.

To sum it up, is there any chance then to interrupt the restoring process and display Windows' bootloader to choose Ubuntu from there?

Comment: Yes, you need to install GRUB so it's the main bootloader (i.e., it loads first and can load the Windows bootloader later).  This requires some manual configuration.  There's probably a question somewhere on Stack Exchange about installing GRUB as a main bootloader, if not the folks at the Ubuntu forums could lead you in the right direction.