# Win7 cannot sleep because of GRUB

Tags: windows-7, linux, partitioning, grub, gparted

I have Win7 on an MBR HDD for 6 years now, that was my primary operation system, but I intend to use Linux instead.

[image: sdb]

At least I am trying out several Linux distros on another HDD, which I set to GPT from Windows.

[image: sda]

That HDD is sda, so by booting first the GRUB menu starts, and I can select Windows 7 booting from sdb if I want.

After a while I noticed that I cannot put Windows 7 in sleep mode, it logs out, but nothing happens after that. I am not sure whether this had been the situation in the beginning (1.5 months ago) of this multi boot experiment or I got this "feature" later.

I checked the sda and noticed that I have 2 small partitions. One is unknown with msftres flag, and one is the fat32 I created for GPT booting. I got a screenshot from that:

[image: partitioning]

I am pretty sure I wanted to have only a single ~250MB FAT32 partition for GPT booting, but the installer created 2 partitions. I pressed the back button, because I forgot to add the biosgrub type (and I read somewhere that it is needed for GPT booting) and I made this screenshot then. I think I did not notice that I have 2 partitions, not a single FAT32, because I was concentrating on taking screenshots.

Now my question is that is there a chance, that these 2 partitions cause that Windows is not capable of sleeping? If not, what can possibly cause this kind of problem?

**Edit:**

I attached the BIOS power management settings:
[image: bios power]

As far as I understand S3 should be enough, so the problem is not there.

I removed every pendrive, so USB devices does not cause the issue. Sleeping worked for 6 years with the current mouse, keyboard, monitor and UPS, so their USB connections are not the cause.

I checked with GRUB Win7 loader and BIOS F12 direct boot. The problem occurs only with GRUB. So the following statement of Christian Isaksson

> No, partition layout and/or GRUB has nothing to do with Windows sleep
>   mode.

is not true.

Comment: Here is a duplicate http://superuser.com/questions/487157/windows-wont-sleep-after-booting-from-grub

Answer (score 2):

No, partition layout and/or GRUB has nothing to do with Windows sleep mode. I suggest you look over your BIOS settings for energy saving as well as check your hardware, sometimes certain devices can prevent the computer from entering sleep mode. I've personally had a USB hub which gave me similar issues.

Comment: I am certain this is related somehow to distro testing, since it has worked well for 6 years, and this grub booting is the only thing I changed lately. I got 2 pendrives attached, one contains a Linux iso, the other is for saving screenshots, etc... Maybe these cause this problem.

Comment: I removed the pendrives, but no luck. Checking the BIOS is a great idea. I needed to upgrade it to use GPT, and it did not keep the old settings, so I had to set the CPU multiplier, USB keyboard and mouse, etc... again. Maybe the energy saving settings aren't properly set. I'll check them.

Comment: I edited the question. The problem is with GRUB booting. It works perfectly when I select the sdb booting from BIOS and don't use the sda GRUB.