# Prevent windows from "sleep saving" and overwriting shared partition

Tags: linux, windows, partitioning

Is there a way to disable Windows to overwrite my shared partition with it's old memory version?

Sometimes the juice runs out, and on reboot, I forget that Windows was last and boot into Linux. A few days later I may boot into Windows, and it will overwrite all my work with what it remembers is the last state it saw.

This is not good. I would prefer Windows not remember anything in this way, and prefer Emacs autosave feature instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That’s not possible. The very point of hibernation is to preserve the complete state of the operating system. This also includes mounted file systems. If that were not possible, stuff like opened files would have to be forcibly closed, instantly crashing the OS upon resume.

That is why Windows locks its boot manager, so you cannot boot into other Windows installations. It doesn’t account for Linux, naturally.

Linux behaves the same when hibernating, by the way. [Modifying its mounted file systems will result in bad things](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/power/swsusp.txt?id=HEAD).

See also [here](https://superuser.com/questions/39532/hibernating-and-booting-into-another-os-will-my-filesystems-be-corrupted).

Comment: Then would disabling hibernation work? (Not sure if Hibernate is still the correct term; I'm in Windows 7.) Or maybe setting power options so it shuts down safely, on low battery?

Comment: Thanks for the links, I have some reading to do, and it may be time to reconsider my shared partition habit.