# Does Linux support NTFS file system

Tags: linux, ubuntu, filesystems, fedora, ntfs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is NTFS on Ubuntu stable?](https://superuser.com/questions/32838/is-ntfs-on-ubuntu-stable)

Does Linux *(Fedora + Ubuntu)* support NTFS file-system. They are known to support ext file system. I want to have same file system for both the windows and linux.

Comment: -1, Question does not show research effort. It's pretty easy to find [documentation about NTFS in Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MountingWindowsPartitions), for example.

Comment: @slhck How can you say that ! I searched on google and couldn't find intent results

Comment: I found that page by entering "ntfs ubuntu". I get more than seven million results for that query alone. It's *really* not that hard to find information online. What did you search for, if I may ask?

Comment: @slhck [i got this](http://bit.ly/KgfeHl)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linux supports NTFS using the *ntfs-3g* FUSE driver. However, it is not recommended to use NTFS or any other FUSE filesystem for the Linux root partition (`/`), due to the added complexity. (NTFS for `/home` would be okay.)

Comment: I wouldn't recommend NTFS for `/home` either, because you can't set POSIX ownership or permissions on it.

Comment: @Shadur: But you can. See the ntfs-3g manual.